# DynamoDB many-to-many relationships, or, should I use Dynamo at all?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We are currently setting up a new application which is so far mostly serverless. Now we are thinking about using DynamoDB for our back-end (because it is fast, 'new' and shiny), therefore I am trying to wrap my head around how to transform our relational model in order to design a good DynamoDB schema.

A very simplified example would be: we have shops which have different attributes (like address etc.) and we have users uniquely identified by their username and other attributes as well, which are allowed to access the information of the shops.

- Shops

  - Shopname (unique)
  - Address
- Users

  - Username (unique)
  - Real name

The use case I am interested in is:
I want to query with a username and get all shops he has access to including their attributes, i.e. their address.

Attempt 1:

```
PK            | SK            | info_data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
store1        | store1        | { address: ABC street, 12345 Anywhere } 
store2        | store2        | { address: XYZ street, 54321 Somewhere }
user1         | user1         | { name: Mr. Nobody }
user2         | user2         | { name: Mr. Anybody }
user1         | store1        | {}
user2         | store1        | {}
user2         | store2        | {}
```

Here I query with the username and get all stores he has access to, but then, I have to query for every store again to get the information.

Attempt 2:

```
PK            | SK            | info_data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
user1         | user1         | { name: Mr. Nobody }
user2         | user2         | { name: Mr. Anybody }
user1         | store1        | { address: ABC street, 12345 Anywhere }
user2         | store1        | { address: ABC street, 12345 Anywhere }
user2         | store2        | { address: XYZ street, 54321 Somewhere }
```

Here I query with the username and get all stores he has access to including the information about the stores in the same query. But I have duplicated data everywhere. 
Therefore, when I change the address of a store, I have to go through all occurrences of that store to change it. Of course, can simplify this by a new global index but I still have to do this.

Because I am new to this I am considering that I am missing something essential here. For the example problem it is not that bad, combined with some other such relations, hierarchies and so on we have in our real data I wonder if a relational database would be better suited? I really want to make this work, just I do not know anymore if it is not possible/feasible or if I just insist on not giving up :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Non-relational databases are best suited for GREAT amount of incoming data, they are developed to be fast on writing content, i don't think it is best suited for your specific use case.

You should consider using and RDS database, Aurora DB (already have great performance without customization). As you are creating your database select the IOPS Optimized type so you can reach maximum writing and reading speeds. With this, your DB performance will be better than with Dynamo and you would be able to keep your actual structure.

Answering your question now:
A value (column) can be a scalar, a map or an array. If a user can have multiple shops, assuming you are going down the linking rather than embedding and denormalized route you would store an Arrayof shopname's in each user (or the other way round).
Like:

```
{ 
    User: “Mr. Nobody”,
    Shops: [
        { address: ABC street, 12345 Anywhere }, 
        { address: AC street, 12345 Anywhere }, 
        { address: BC street, 12345 Anywhere }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of DynamoDB is not only the fact that it is a non-relational DB, but each Table is an independent resource in your AWS cloud.
I have started a project using DynamoDB, but moved to MongoDB. The reasons were:

1. Lack of flexibility.
2. Lack of a good ORM package.
3. Queries complex to build. Team learning curve.

I think it would be a great solution if you need to keep a huge amount of data in a DB, but without the whole DB management and structure.

For your case I would suggest maybe AuroraDB?